# folder created not found in external storage android studio device explorer

Tags: android, android-studio

am trying to create a folder in the android emulator external storage
using this code:

```
File sdIconStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/rafik/"); 
sdIconStorageDir.mkdirs();
```

it worked well before but now I can't find the directory in the external storage of the android studio emulator using the device explorer,
the `sdIconStorageDir.mkdirs()`; return `true` but the folder is missing,
however, the folder is created successfully and it's visible when I use my physical phone so What is my problem?

Comment: `sdIconStorageDir.mkdirs(); return true ` We do not see that you check the return value. Further you should only call mkdirs() if the directory does not exist yet. Please update your code. Also with checking the return value.

Comment: It should be: `File sdIconStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "rafik"); ` (Not that it would solve your problem.. only better code).

Comment: The problem is that you forgot to synchronise the parent directory. (Click right and Synchronize).

Comment: thanks @blackapps I updated the code I always synchronise the parent directory but didn't solved, it worked before I think that the problem is in android studio after updating

Answer (score 0):

Update the code like that. And also give the permission for READ And WRITE External Storage in Manifest File.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/FolderName");
```

Comment: still not solved, the code works well on the physical phone, may be  it's an android studio problem after updating

Comment: I already gave the READ And WRITE External Storage in Manifest File